# Application in DroidScript is crashed when method OnMessage from sms service receive sms with symbolic phone number

Tags: javascript, droidscript

So, code

```
function Onstage() {
  sms = app.CreateSMS();
  sms.SetOnMessage(sms_OnMessage);
}

function sms_OnMessage (number, message) {
  app.ShowPopup(number + ': ' + message);
}
```

is crashed when sms with symbolic phone number comes.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, function OnStart(), not Onstage()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!starred/androidscript/lmCi2wKTqOs

If link will be broken - find similar theme in "DroidScript" group.